# Can we distribute a package before sending it for the security code Review?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, 2gp, partner

Basically, we are an ISV partner and want to deploy our App to the AppExchange for our customers. But due to the shortage of time for the security review, we're unable to upload it to the AppExchange. So, we want to deploy our package to the customer's Org before the Security review without breaking any Salesforce rules.

Comment: Technically you can (though you won't be able to create patch releases, only major/minor release upgrades). However, you would be violating your master agreement with Salesforce so this is probably not a great idea.

Comment: Your comment is actually an answer, @PhilW

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can install an "uncertified" app on a customer's org (something allowed because customers can create their own apps as packages if they so choose). Note that you cannot create patch releases for a package that hasn't yet passed security review, meaning any bug fixes etc. can only be made using major/minor release upgrades.

However, **you would be violating your master agreement with Salesforce** since you would be charging your customers for this package, so this is probably not a great idea. The agreement ([this](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/SPPAMay12020Final.pdf) is the May 2020 version) specifically says:

> Partner shall not distribute a Partner Application
> unless such Partner Application has successfully passed the Partner Application Security Review.